# Heisenberg's Unified Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, unified-theories

While searching in the Internet, I came to know about Werner Heisenberg's attempt to obtain an Unified Field Theory (see the book **Introduction to Unified Field Theory of Elementary Particles**). But also it has been mentioned that since this theory is non-renormalizable, it wasn't a successful candidate for the UFT. Was non-renormalizability the only reason? If not then what were the other reasons? Specifically, my question is that was the theory abandoned because it was *wrong* or because it wasn't *practically efficient*? If it was wrong then can some instances be provided?

Comment: Can you give more details on what the theory actually is? BTW it is extremely unlikely that it would be possible for anyone from the 1950s [Wikipedia says Heisenberg wrote about his unified field theory in 1953] to have written down a successful "theory of everything" given that the standard model was still 20 years from being constructed.

Comment: @Andrew: In fact Heisenberg wrote a book on this theory which is called the Nonlinear Spinor Field Theory. I can't find a link to the book. However, [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftheor.jinr.ru%2F~spin2012%2Ftalks%2Fs5%2FObukhov.pdf&ei=2SIuVObjIse8ugSzp4C4DA&usg=AFQjCNGbeQa83EwMhJBexbwVB4hfUnHdhg&bvm=bv.76802529,d.c2E) may give you some insight. Although I know it is hardly enough.

Comment: @Andrew: Also see [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDgQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvixra.org%2Fpdf%2F1102.0057v1.pdf&ei=6SMuVLuYAYbguQTqtYHQBQ&usg=AFQjCNFUpeM8d94NcDnxvuM22tacn8WlVw).

Comment: Please also see [this](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/24285/heisenbergs-unified-field-theory).

Comment: But ... [this answer](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/24285/heisenbergs-unified-field-theory?show=24305#a24305)  explains why it was "wrong".

Answer (score 2):

Good references were provided by Conifold [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/heisenbergs-last-work-on-a-non-linear-generalization-of-quantum-mechanics/13596#13596).

To sum up, there were several problems with this initial approach: spinors where observable physical objects due to their dimension of $-\frac{3}{2}$, the introduction of a dimensioned coupling constant lead to non-renormalizability, etc.

You may want to check out this video proposing changes to this initial approach, leading to some quite interesting results:

[A non-linear spinor theory of elementary particles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDiuQqfVm3Y)